# Better way of updating pandas dataframe while iterating through it

Tags: python, pandas

While iterating through a pandas dataframe and making changes, what is a better way to update the dataframe with the changes? An example below, right now I'm using indexer `ix` to locate the row to update which I believe is not the best way especially if data is big:

```
print df

id | A     | B
01 | 374   | 2014-02-01 04:45:04.401502
02 | 284   | 2014-03-12 21:23:12.401502
03 | 183   | 2014-02-01 09:12:08.401502

for row in df.itertuples():
    id = row[1]
    col_a = row[2]
    col_b = row[3]

    N = random.randint(2,5)
    for i in xrange(0, N): 
       new_col_a = col_a + 1
       new_col_b = datetime.datetime.now()

       #update dataframe's A, B respectively
       df.ix[df['id'] == id, ['A', 'B']] = [col_a, col_b]  


print df

id | A     | B
01 | 374   | 2014-02-01 04:45:04.401502
01 | 375   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
01 | 376   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
01 | 377   | 2014-12-07 07:45:04.401502
02 | 284   | 2014-03-12 21:23:12.401502
02 | 285   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
02 | 286   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
03 | 183   | 2014-02-01 09:12:08.401502
03 | 184   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
03 | 185   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
03 | 186   | 2016-12-07 07:45:04.401502
```

Comment: it seems you only wants to change the column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very nice solution, because loops.

So first `apply` for each row of `df` custom function, where create new `DataFrame` and append it to list `dfs`. Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) it and apply function, which can works out of custom function :

```
np.random.seed(10)
dfs = []
def expand(x):
    N = np.random.choice([2,3,4])
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.values.tolist()], columns=x.index).reindex(range(N))
    df.A = df.A.fillna(1).cumsum()
    df.insert(1,'prevA', df.A.shift())
    dfs.append(df)

df.apply(expand, axis=1)

df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df1.A = df1.A.astype(int)
df1.id = df1.id.ffill().astype(int)
df1.prevA = df1.prevA.bfill().astype(int)
df1.B = df1.B.fillna(pd.datetime.now())

print (df1)

   id  prevA    A                          B
0   1    374  374 2014-02-01 04:45:04.401502
1   1    374  375 2016-12-07 10:48:14.299336
2   1    375  376 2016-12-07 10:48:14.299336
0   2    284  284 2014-03-12 21:23:12.401502
1   2    284  285 2016-12-07 10:48:14.299336
2   2    285  286 2016-12-07 10:48:14.299336
0   3    183  183 2014-02-01 09:12:08.401502
1   3    183  184 2016-12-07 10:48:14.299336
```